# Different comment-start for end of line comments for custom major-mode

Tags: emacs, comments, major-mode

When I type `M-;`, this invokes `comment-dwim` which, on a line containing text and with no active region, I believe ultimately invokes `comment-indent` to add an in-line or end-of-line comment.

In this custom major-mode, `comment-start` is set to `"# "` (and `comment-style` is `'plain`) but this should only apply at the very start of a line.  How do I get an in-line comment to start with `";; "`?

Example of current behaviour:

```
# Whole line comment
SOME CODE HERE # in-line comment
```

Example of required behaviour:

```
# Whole line comment
SOME CODE HERE ;; in-line comment
```

Additionally, `comment-region` works perfectly when region starts at the beginning of a line and `comment-start` is always left-aligned for this. However, halfway through a line, it will begin the comment with `comment-start` (`#`).

Comment: If you start from `SOME CODE HERE in-line-comment` then select `in-line comment` and hit `M-;` I strongly suspect that you'll see that "comment-region *doesn't* work perfectly".

Comment: @Stefan I see what you mean.  I have never used `comment-region` halfway through a line until this very moment.  I will edit accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to make custom syntax table as described at [Emacs Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsSyntaxTable) and [ErgoEmacs](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_syntax_table.html):

For example, for my cql-mode I use following to distinguish between `/* .. */` for block comments, and `--` or `//` for single-line/end-of line comments.

```
(defvar cql-mode-syntax-table
  (let ((st (make-syntax-table)))
    (modify-syntax-entry ?/ ". 124b" st)
    (modify-syntax-entry ?* ". 23" st)
    ;; double-dash starts comments
    (modify-syntax-entry ?- ". 12b" st)
    ;; newline and formfeed end comments
    (modify-syntax-entry ?\n "> b" st)
    (modify-syntax-entry ?\f "> b" st)
    st)
  "Syntax table for CQL mode")
```

and in declaration of derived mode I specify:

```
(set-syntax-table cql-mode-syntax-table)
```

And meaning is described in documentation for function `modify-syntax-entry`: for `/` - `1` means that character can start comment, `2` means that it could be also 2nd character in sequence, `4` - that it finishes comment, `b` is that it could be comment type `b`. for `*` it says that it could be second or second to last character of comment type `a` (default type).

Similarly, for `-` it declares that it could be first & second characters in comment type `b`.

In your case it could look following way (not tested):

```
(defvar some-mode-syntax-table
  (let ((st (make-syntax-table)))
    (modify-syntax-entry ?# ". 1b" st)
    ;; double-; starts comments
    (modify-syntax-entry ?; ". 12b" st)
    ;; newline and formfeed end comments
    (modify-syntax-entry ?\n "> b" st)
    (modify-syntax-entry ?\f "> b" st)
    st)
  "Syntax table for some mode")
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the pointers. The syntax table had no effect on how comments are created/detected in `comment-dwim` though.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to write a solution to this:

I noted that `comment-indent-function` is a variable which holds (from emacs `describe-variable`):

> Function to compute desired indentation for a comment.
>   This function is called with no args with point at the beginning of
>   the comment's starting delimiter and should return either the desired
>   column indentation or nil.
>   If nil is returned, indentation is delegated to `indent-according-to-mode'.

This allows creation of a custom function which can replace `comment-start` and return `nil` to allow default indentation, noting that when this function is called, `point` will be "at the beginning of the comment's starting delimiter" (i.e. at the beginning of `comment-start`). The following is now included in my custom major mode `comment-indent` (through `comment-dwim`) now behaves as required:

```
;;
(defun my-major-mode ()
  (interactive)
  (kill-all-local-variables)
  ...
  (make-local-variable 'comment-start)
  (make-local-variable 'comment-indent-function)
  (make-local-variable 'comment-indent-start)
  ...
  (setq major-mode 'my-major-mode
    ...
    comment-start "# "
    comment-indent-function 'my-comment-indent
    comment-indent-start ";; "
    )
  ...
)

(defun my-comment-indent ()
  "Replace indented '#' with ';;'"
  (interactive)
  (if (not (looking-back ".\\{1\\}")) ;; if comment is left aligned
      0                               ;; leave it left aligned (return 0)
    (progn                        ;; else: don't return until we're ready
      (looking-at comment-start)            ;; find "#"
      (replace-match comment-indent-start)) ;; replace with ";;"
      nil)))                      ;; return `nil' for default indentation
```

Comment: Function is a bit raw, but it does the job.